# How do I generate my public key hash?

Tags: hash

I have most of the data for my ICO wallet except the public key hash.

The PDF that came with that data is gone, so no I cant go find it there.

Is there no way I can generate to myself?

I have the eth address and private key I sent from, as well as the email, 15 words and password.

Comment: **Easy way:**

Use: https://wallet.kukai.app/import